# Django ElasticSearch / pyes : How to search with two filters?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, pyes

I need to add another param 'type' to my query to filter with

This is what I have right now and it works for me:

```
    conn = pyes.ES(settings.ES_URL)
    query_string = self.request.GET['q'].lower()
    type = self.request.GET['type'].lower()#not used yet!

    ...

    query1 = pyes.MultiMatchQuery(self.FIELDS_SEARCH, query_string, operator='and')

    search1 = pyes.Search(query=query1, filter=filters, fields=self.RESPONSE_FIELDS, size=num, index_boost=1)

    response = conn.search_multi([search1, search2], indices_list=[es_alias] * 2, doc_types_list=['asset', 'people'] * 2)

    response._do_search()
```

How can I add filtering by param "type"?

Comment: are you talking about `_type`? or is `type` a field in your index?

Comment: type is a param I want to filter with `type = self.request.GET['type']`

Comment: same as query_string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [bool query](https://pyes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/references/pyes.query.html#pyes.query.BoolQuery)

```
query1 = pyes.MultiMatchQuery(self.FIELDS_SEARCH, query_string, operator='and')

typequery = pyes.QueryStringQuery(query="type_value",default_field="type")

combinequery = pyes.BoolQuery(must=[query1, typequery])

searchquery = pyes.Search(query=combinequery,filter=filters, fields=self.RESPONSE_FIELDS, size=num, index_boost=1)
```

Here is the link to [query string](http://pyes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/references/pyes.query.html#pyes.query.QueryStringQuery), you can replace `must` with `should` if you want `OR` condition.

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks, but I still need to keep "search2", do I just replace "search1" with "searchquery" that you wrote like this: `conn.search_multi([serachquery , search2])` ?

Comment: although I am not 100%, try replacing it. It should work going by the ES api for multiple search but I am not abel to find docs for pyes for multi_search, could you help me find it?

Comment: But if I replace 
`search1 = pyes.Search(query=query1, filter=filters, fields=self.RESPONSE_FIELDS, size=num, index_boost=1)`
by 
`searchquery = pyes.Search(query=combinequery)` 
how about all the params I have in search1 (filter,fields,size and index) ??

Comment: here : http://pyes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/references/pyes.es.html#pyes.es.ES.search_multi

Comment: P.S: QueryStringQuery is not working sine I use pyes==0.20.1 (yeah I know!! I can't update now)

Comment: I replaced it with StringQuery

Comment: Yes, you can put all the params in it, I have edited my answer, then replace search1 with searchquery, let me know if it doesn't work.